# How does blockchain programming differ from regular programming?

Tags: blockchain

Blockchain seems to be the new hot thing and I'm curious as to how it's different from a programmer's standpoint.

Like if I'm using Solidity, don't I still apply object oriented principles? How would it differ from Ruby? Isn't contract oriented programming basically just like object oriented programming but with money (in the case of Solidity, Ether) involved?

Or perhaps they are similar, and it is just that blockchain programming is more transparent and secure since it is trustless.

In conclusion I am just trying to wrap my head around how I can transition my current programming skills to blockchain. Thanks.

Comment: What are you talking about sounds more like programming smart contracts. Solidity is another programming language which is used to build smart contracts. Its similar to Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to make the assumption that you are interested in programming Public Blockchain, for which Ethereum is the most widely available, hence "Blockchain Programming" will refer to programming on public blockchain networks.

There are a variety of concerns when programming public blockchain networks:

1. **Immutability**: This is the gift and the curse of the public blockchain. Anything you commit to the ledger be easily modified by a `pull`. Therefore extra care has to be taken with regards to getting it right on the first try.
2. **Security**: Your code is there for the world to see. This transparency also opens the door to malicious actors (or overtly exuberant beginners) to cause significant harm . See [THE DAO](https://www.coindesk.com/understanding-dao-hack-journalists/) and [Parity Hack](https://medium.com/chain-cloud-company-blog/parity-multisig-hack-again-b46771eaa838).
3. **Trust Layer**: Block chain programming adds add extra "trust layer" to the OSI model. Therefore most of your application logic is driven from the blockchain. You then need to use another intermediator (Web3 in Ethereum's case) to communicate with the application layer, then plug that into the experience layer.
4. **Gas (or its equivalent)**: For ethereum, the concept of gas was introduced to prevent "infinity loop attacks" . The presents the following problems: (i) The cost of running applications becomes very expensive (Ethereum is now at $820 dollar (ii) Programming for this requires an intimate understanding of the computational costs of each of your operations.
5. **Through put**: Public blockchains require transactions to be propagated to the entire network. This introduces latency, as every node in the network has to run your operations See [Cryto Kitties](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijvrausJbYAhULLMAKHZyqCIkQqQIINSgAMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2Fnews%2Ftechnology-42237162&usg=AOvVaw2c8EKxcOowY9qXC8_q_SnF).

This list is far from exhaustive, but I hope it starts to shed light on the differences and aide you on your journey.

References:

- [Difference Between Public Blockchains and Private Blockchains](https://www.coindesk.com/information/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-permissioned-blockchains/)
- [Formal Verification Ethereum](https://www.coindesk.com/paranoia-rules-ethereum-smart-contract-security-advancing/)